# Why are my methods returning different values for the same variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a double called time. I cannot determine why I can pass the double to a method in another class, but the same method cannot ask for said double from the class it exists in.

My header file looks something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) double time;
```

My implementation goes something like this:

```
@implementation MainVewController

@synthesize time;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{ 
    startTime = NSDate.date;
}

- (double) returnTime {
    NSLog (@"time is disappearing?? %f", time);
    return time;
}

- (double) logTime {
    NSLog (@"for some reason, this one is working and returns a value %f", time);
    return time;
}
```

My other class is asking for my double:

```
@synthesize mainViewController = _mainViewController ;

- (MainViewController *)mainViewController {
    if (!_mainViewController) _mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return _mainViewController;
}

- (BOOL)getTime {
    double timeGotten = [self.mainViewController returnTime];
    // why does this return 0?
    return TRUE;
}
```

The time variable is continually being updated within the MainVewController:

```
time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: startTime];
```

Comment: Where is the time variable declared in relation to the two methods?

Comment: How can you say this has not been asked somewhere else ? FYI, You DO NOT RETURN A DOUBLE .... and your double `time` may not exist. Set a break point, First try to see if you self.mainViewController exists, then check the value of time and please RETURN it in case `timeGotten` needs it.

Comment: Both returnTime and logTime will return the same value for the code you have shown. As far as we can see, you never set the value of time.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I updated the code some more to give you an idea of what time should be, it's in seconds, and yes, both methods should be returning the same value, but they're not! Here are some logs: 2012-06-20 13:19:01.084: time is disappearing?? 0.000000
2012-06-20 13:19:01.084: for some reason, this one is working and returns a value 9.901174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your "other class" asks for `self.mainViewController`, it creates a new one.  I'm guessing here but, since it's called `MainViewController`, there's probably already one of those in existence before "other class" creates its own new one.

That first `MainViewController` is likely where the updates are happening.

Answer (score 0):

You state in the function declarations that the function return a variable of type `double`, but you never put in a return statement returning a value of type `double`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not telling the full story. I have replicated your code in a new cocoa application. There are a few minor differences, however the logic remains unchanged.

My `AppDelegate.h` looks like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) double time;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m` looks like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize time;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDate * startTime = [NSDate date];
    time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: startTime];

    NSLog(@"Return time %f",[self returnTime]);
    NSLog(@"Log time %f", [self logTime]);
}

- (double) returnTime {
    return time;
}

- (double) logTime {
    return time;
}

@end
```

Copy this code into a new cocoa project and run the app and you will see this runs correctly. On my machine, the console output looks like this:

```
2012-06-21 20:02:17.832 test[298:403] Return time 0.000003
2012-06-21 20:02:17.833 test[298:403] Log time 0.000003
```

There are a number of things that could be wrong with your code but most of these are just speculation without seeing any further code. 
First, You could have multiple instances of `mainViewController` as mention by *Phillip Mills* (you could have an instance in a nib file and also be passing in an instances the nibs file owner for example) which means you are calling methods which are passing back different time variables.

You also say your application is continually updating the time variable. First of all, what triggers this update? Secondly, if the variable is being continuously updated it is unlikely to return the same value as the variable could have been updated between the two method calls.

Note: there was also a small error in your code. This line:

```
NSLog ("for some reason, this one is working and returns a value %f", time);
```

should be (notice the @ sign):

```
NSLog (@"for some reason, this one is working and returns a value %f", time);
```

I went ahead and edited your post to correct this as I don't think this is the problem as the code won't even compile on my machine if the @ symbol is ommited.